# Selecting values that begins with specified value located in the same or other table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to select records that begin same as first but without it. First one could change depending on user's choice so solution must be 'dynamic'. I tried putting substring containing first three chracters of first record to NOT LIKE () function but it doesn't work, got messege that 'like (text) doesn't exist'. Could I get help to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.4 and I no longer get error, instead of this my query that is posted below returns entire table.

```
select * from codes where code not like substring((select code from codes where id = 1) from 1 for 3);

Table:
+--------+-----------+
|code_id |code       |
|[PK]int |varchar(10)|
+--------+-----------+
|1       |00011111   |
|2       |11111111   |
|3       |11122222   |
|4       |00022222   |
|5       |00033333   |
+--------+-----------+

Result:
+--------+-----------+
|code_id |code       |
|[PK]int |varchar(10)|
+--------+-----------+
|4       |00022222   |
|5       |00033333   |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: You forgot to provide your version on Postgres, the query you tried (even if it's not working)  and the table definition showing data types, constraints, etc. (`\d tbl` in psql). Also, error messages should be copied *verbatim*.

Comment: it is not like() function it is LIKE operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE codes (
  code_id int PRIMARY KEY
, code text);
```

This does the job:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM  (SELECT left(code, 3) || '%' AS pattern FROM codes WHERE code_id = 1) x
JOIN   codes c ON c.code LIKE x.pattern
WHERE  c.code_id <> 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/284ec/1)

Use [`left()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) (simpler, cheaper), [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) - <strike>`NOT LIKE`</strike> would be backwards for (quote) `records that begin same as first` - and append the wildcard `%` to the pattern.

If your table is big (no use for small tables), an **index** will make this *fast*:

```
CREATE INDEX codes_text_pattern_ops_idx ON codes(code text_pattern_ops);
```

Details:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Answer (score 1):

[[NOT] LIKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) (which as a commenter stated is not written as `like()` because it isn't a function) is a bit different when it comes to matching. The percent symbol is your wild card and you need it to match the rest of the field.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE code LIKE '000%';
```

If you were to just do `LIKE '000'`, that would be equivalent to `code = '000'`, which wouldn't match anything. Or, conversely, `NOT LIKE '000'` would match everything.

To get what you're after involves something a bit messier to achieve the previous example by using [concat() and substr()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT *
  FROM codes
 WHERE code NOT LIKE concat(
    (SELECT substr(code::text, 1, 3) FROM codes WHERE id = 1), '%'
);
```

We use substr() in the sub-select to return just the first 3 characters in the code column up to concat(). Then we use concat() to generate a suitable string for `NOT LIKE` to use.

If the `code` column is already text-like, you can drop the `::text` cast, but it wouldn't hurt anything to keep it there. substring() and substr() are effectively the same, but we can shorten up the query a bit with substr().

Comment: `LIKE` without wildcard wouldn't do the job, but it wouldn't produce an error, either.

Comment: I tried something like that before I posted here. It doesn't solve my problem because it won't work if first record would begin with 111. Question is how to write anything like 'dynamic regexp'.

Comment: @Jesion, answer edited. I hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you don't need the like and the '%'

```
SELECT *
FROM codes c
WHERE c.id > 1
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM codes x
  WHERE LEFT(x.code, 3) = LEFT(c.code, 3)
  AND x.id = 1
  );
```